# application.js not loading in Development (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

Last week i was working with starting a new Ruby on Rails Application was going to build it in Rails 4 but had many complications so i uninstalled the rvm version of rails

now one of my rails 3 project is having issues loading assets. (others are fine)

I have uninstalled all rubies and started fresh and have everything back except for my assets

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 192.168.1.184 at 2015-03-09 14:14:22 -0500
2015-03-09 14:14:22 INFO -- Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2015-03-09 14:14:22] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2015-03-09 14:14:22] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2015-03-09 14:14:22] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2015-03-09 14:14:22] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2015-03-09 14:14:22] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
2015-03-09 14:14:23 INFO --
```

Console log

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.geocomplete
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require jgrowl
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require rails.validations
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require amazingslider
//= require initslider-1
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


group :development do
  gem "bullet", '~> 4.4.0'
  gem "spring"

  gem 'rails_best_practices'
end

group :test do

  gem 'selenium-webdriver' #used for capybara features where js => true
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'watchr'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'capybara', '2.2.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'resque_spec'
  #These are for mac only
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
end
group :production do
  gem 'god', '0.13.1'
  gem 'whenever'
  gem 'gauges-rails'

end

gem 'client_side_validations', '3.2.5'
gem 'tzip'
gem 'i18n'
gem 'json'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'devise', "2.1.2"
gem 'devise-encryptable', "0.1.1"
gem 'cancan'
gem 'httparty'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'rgeo', '0.3.20'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '0.6.3'
gem 'rgeo-geojson', '0.2.3'
gem 'rgeo-activerecord', '0.5.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 2.2.8'

gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'twitter_bootstrap_form_for'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '0.2.2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'less-rails'

# only Jquery
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1.3'
#---added----
gem 'jquery-ui-themes'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'



gem 'mechanize'
gem 'chronic', '~>0.7.0'
gem 'resque', '~> 1.21.0', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'redis', '3.0.1'
gem 'ruby-gmail'
gem 'mime'
gem 'roo'
gem 'pony'
#dont think we even need Mysql2 Gem since using postgres
#gem 'mysql2'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano', '2.14.2'
# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

#Austin Added new relic gem for newrelic.com monitoring of transactions and database'
#gem 'newrelic_rpm'

#gems for paypal sdk
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'
gem 'paypal-sdk-merchant'
gem 'paypal-recurring'

gem 'credit_card_validations'

#PDF Generation of invoices
gem 'prawn'
gem 'levenshtein'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
platforms :ruby do
  group :development do

    #Austin added better errors for development display of errors
    gem 'better_errors'

    #Austin added binding of caller for development in order to enable REPL and local instance variable inspection of variables on errors
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
  end

  # Use unicorn as the app server

  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.2'
  gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.6.2'
  gem 'libv8', '3.3.10.4'
  gem 'iconv'
end
gem 'recurly', '2.1.8'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'google-analytics-rails'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'feedjira'
```

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's your problem, but you should avoid using `require_tree`. It's always better to explicitly define the include order of your assets.

Comment: Remove progressively more `//= require` lines from your `application.js` file to try and pinpoint the problem. Make sure you ran `bundle` after whatever you did with RVM and the `rails` gem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion on the tree. i have ran bundle and verified that all gems have been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the nature of this kind of problem, I can't fix it for you, but I can give you a list of things to verify that are very likely to be where the problem comes from.

- Possible scenario is that a script tag contains calls to jQuery before the application.js file is loaded. Check in your HTML (including template) where is located the loading application.js, and verify is any call to `$` is done before it
- Another scenario is that you are loading several manifest and another manifest is calling to jQuery and is also loaded before application.js. Check on this in your HTML files.